# Queue\SerializesModels removes variables Laravel Event

Tags: php, laravel, serialization, laravel-events, laravel-broadcast

I'm using an event which broadcasts an user object.
The user object contains

```
  "id":2,
  "name":"Clark",
  "surname":"Beer",
  "email":"schultz.arthur@example.com",
  "role":"user",
  "information":{  
     "user_id":2,
     "bio":"Dicta fugit voluptas fugiat doloremque.",
     "profile_picture_id":2,
     "image":{  
        "id":2,
        "path":"https:\/\/lorempixel.com\/640\/640\/people\/?54438"
     }
  }
```

But the problem is, the broadcast sends only the user model without the "information" child object, this is caused by the SerializesModels.

The broadcast works fine when I delete the SerializesModels import, but it would be nice too still use the SerializesModels trait.

Is there a way to include the childobjects while using the SerializesModels trait?

```
class searchUserEvent implements ShouldBroadcastNow {
   use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

   /**
    * Create a new event instance.
    *
    * @return void
    */

    public $users;

    public function __construct($users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    /**
    * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
    *
    * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
    */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('searchUser');
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Sadly I didn't, but I used it without the import since it was a school project.